# React component not updated when stored as usestate variable

Tags: reactjs, ajax, react-hooks

In my App.tsx, I'm using a useState variable waitMessage to store string and a useState variable waitComp to store a component. waitMessage is passed as props to waitComp to show any text message whenever its values is updated. In useEffect, I'm calling an AJAX request, and updating the value of waitMessage, but the same is not updating the message showing in waitComp. The same component is getting updated when not stored as useSate variable. Following is my code:

```
function App() {
    const dependencies: string[] = [];
    const [waitMessage, setWaitMessage] = useState("Waiting for Server Auth...");
    const wait = <Wait text={waitMessage}/>;
    const [waitComp, setWaitComp] = useState(wait);

    const checkStatus = () => {
        const ajaxSet: AjaxType = {
            callback(request: XMLHttpRequest): void {
                const response = request.response;
                console.info(response); // Getting expected response
                setWaitMessage("Response Received...");
                // Updating waitMessage, but not waitComp
            }, params: {}, url: "http://localhost:8080/user/status"
        };
        callAjax(ajaxSet);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        checkStatus();
        return () => {
        };
    }, dependencies);


    return <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
                {waitComp}
            </Route>
            <Route>
                <PageNotFound/>
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    </Router>;
}
```

I need to store the component as useState cause I need to change the component under certain conditions. The wait component is getting updated if I directly use it like this:

```
<Route exact path="/">
    {wait}
</Route>
```

Can you please explain the cause and solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you try removing `waitComp` and just rendering `<Wait text={waitMessage} />` under your `<Route>`, where `{waitComp}` is? I've never seen someone put a component in state before, and I reckon that's got something to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple issues here:

**1) setWaitComp is never called:**

In order to modify **waitComp** you have to call **setWaitComp** after waitMessage has changed. This can be achieved like this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    setWaitComp(<Wait text={waitMessage}/>)
},[waitMessage])
```

**Is this a good solution? No.** The best way in this case is what @Vizard recommended, since nothing but the "text"-prop of your "Wait"-Component changes. Would you replace the component with a different one, that would be different.

**2) why is "wait" being updated:**

By passing"waitMessage" to the text-prop of your "Wait"-Component, every time the "setWaitMessage" a [rerender of your component](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#setstate) is being triggered and the new value of "waitMessage" is being passed to your "Wait"-Component.

Since this is the case, it's only logical to skip the boilerplate code from earlier and do it like this right away:

```
<Wait text={waitMessage}>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any point of storing `<Wait text={waitMessage}/>` in a state.
Instead what you can do is,

```
<Route exact path="/">
  <Wait text={waitMessage}/>
</Route>
```

Once waitMessage is changed, it will render the component again.